# Bug in ActiveMq Broker : WARN [Transport:203] Transport Connection to: StompSocket_1661562307 failed: java.io.IOException: closedOut 1006:null

Tags: java, spring, websocket, activemq-classic

I use embedded broker ActiveMq and connect to it from a JavaScript application. The protocol used is STOMP over WebSocket. XML Config for Spring:

```
<amq:broker id="broker" useJmx="false" persistent="false" brokerId="1" brokerName="locHost">
    <amq:transportConnectors>
        <amq:transportConnector name="websocket" uri="ws://0.0.0.0:6661"/>
    </amq:transportConnectors>
</amq:broker>



<!-- JMS ConnectionFactory to use, configuring the embedded broker using XML -->
<amq:connectionFactory id="jmsFactory" brokerURL="vm://localhost"/>


<bean id="jmsConnectionFactory"
      class="org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory"
      depends-on="broker"
      p:targetConnectionFactory-ref="jmsFactory"
      />

<jms:listener-container
        container-type="default"
        connection-factory="jmsConnectionFactory"
        >
    . . . . .
    <jms:listener destination="toggle"     ref="consumer" method="toggle"      response-destination="toggle"/>

    . . . . .

</jms:listener-container>
```

Also have a few listeners of this form(one of them):

```
@Component
public class Consumer {
   . . . . .
   public String toggle(String message)  {

        return "Responce" + message; 
   }

   . . . . .
}
```

Some listeners are working, but there are those under which there is exception type:

```
09:33:25,196 WARN  [Transport:203] Transport Connection to: StompSocket_1661562307 failed: java.io.IOException: closedOut 1006:null
```

and the message is not getting to the recipient. What can we do?

Comment: 4th May 2015. I still have the problem

Answer (score 0):

Which version of AMQ you are running?

Have you tried, using URL in stomp format:

```
<transportConnectors>
   <transportConnector name="stomp" uri="stomp://localhost:61613"/>
</transportConnectors>
```

The URL starts with `stomp://`

see more details at [Apache Documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/stomp.html)